# Guzzle HTTP async pool request

Tags: php, http, asynchronous, guzzle

I have the following code:

```
$client = new Client($conf);

//Pool of requests
$requests = function ($data) use ($client) {
    yield function () use ($client, $pixel) {
        ....
    }
}
//Pool of fullfilled
$fullfilled = function ($response, $index) use ($data) {
    ...
}
//Pool of rejected
$rejected = function ($reason, $index) use ($data) {
    ...
}

$pool = new Pool($client, $requests($data), [
            'concurrency' => 10, 'fulfilled' => $fullfilled, 'rejected' => $rejected
        ]);

// Initiate the transfers and create a promise
$promise = $pool->promise(); 
$promise->wait();
```

I'm not sure I'm using the "wait" properly, but I want the process to be async.
Currently, the request hangs and if I omit the wait then the pool will not be sent at all.
Ideas?

Comment: Looks fine to me. `wait` is a sync method, so your script is supposed to "hung" until all requests are resolved.

Comment: @AlexBlex But if i omit the wait then the requests are not sent at all...

Comment: Yes, `wait` triggers `curl_multi_exec` to run all your requests in parallel. If you need a truly async, like send http, do something, handle response, you need to `tick` the queue yourself. Look at https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1127 for examples.

Answer (score 1):

The Guzzle documentation describes how to make multiple concurrent requests using promises: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#concurrent-requests

Comment: yes, but this doesnt answer my question because i still have to wait..
$client = new Client();

$requests = function ($total) use ($client) {
    $uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:8126/guzzle-server/perf';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
        yield function() use ($client, $uri) {
            return $client->getAsync($uri);
        };
    }
};

$pool = new Pool($client, $requests(100));